# Jersey Client - How to send List in a form with a POST request

Tags: java, json, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey

I am using the jersey client to send POST requests to a web server. I have generally been building up a *Form* object with key-value pairs. However, I now have to send a *List* within my request. Here's an abridged version of my code

```
// Phone is a POJO consisting of a few Strings
public void request(List<Phone> phones) {
     Form form = new Form();
     form.add("phones", phones);
     ClientResponse response = WebService.getResponseFromServer(form);
     String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
     System.out.println(output);
}

public static ClientResponse getResponseFromServer(Form form) {
    Client client = createClient();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(PATH);

    return webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(ClientResponse.class, form);
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work, and I get a 400 bad request error. When I send a request directly

```
{"phones":[{"areaCode":"217","countryCode":"01","number":"3812565"}]}
```

I have no problems. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example, based on typical POJO serialization, what you need isn't `List<Phone>` but a class with a member `phones` of a type `List<Phone>`, otherwise the payload will look like this:

```
[{"areaCode":"217","countryCode":"01","number":"3812565"}]
```

So first, what you need is a jersey client with JSON serialization feature. You need to include `jersey-json` (along with the `jersey-client`) in your dependencies. Example in Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Create your client like this:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
```

Assuming you have a variable `phones` which is the POJO, you can call this:

```
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, phones);
```

Comment: Do I need to annotate my Phones pojo? I'm getting: Error generating response from the client : com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class Phones, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found

Comment: No, you don't need to. Did you set the `clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);` properly?

Comment: I did, yep. Not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: Which version of jersey are you using?

Comment: jersey 1.19. The problem ended up being a missing dependency to map Pojo's to json. After adding genson to the project, it worked. Thanks for the help.